# If $B$ is a flat $A$-algebra then $B_{\mathrm{red}}$ is a flat $A_{\mathrm{red}}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness

Given a commutative ring $A$ we denote by $A_{\mathrm{red}}$ the ring $A/\mathrm{Nil}(A)$ where $\mathrm{Nil}(A)$ is the nilradical of $A$. It is not difficult to see that this construction is functorial, that is, given a ring morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ there is a natural induced morphism $f_\mathrm{red}:A_\mathrm{red}\rightarrow B_\mathrm{red}$.

> Is it true that if $f:A\rightarrow B$ makes $B$ a flat $A$-algebra then $f_\mathrm{red}:A_\mathrm{red}\rightarrow B_\mathrm{red}$ makes $B_\mathrm{red}$ a flat $A_\mathrm{red}$-algebra?

Comment: This is not true in general and one example is due to Cowsik and Nori. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869376902374

Comment: This seems really interesting but I can see how can I obtain my example from it. It is related with the Hironaka's criterion for Cohen Macaulay?

Comment: @Mohan Ok, know I understand. In the notation of the paper we have $A \hookrightarrow C$ is flat and $A$ is reduced but $A \hookrightarrow \varphi(C)=C_\mathrm{red}$ is not flat. Thanks!!